# Simple Insert Query Returning Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Can anybody find me where is the error exactly as I'm getting really mad

This is my code:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO mk_pay_wages (u_id, year_month, wage) VALUES (14, "2021-06", 900)';

echo $query . '<br>';

$mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error);
```

And this is the mySQL table:

[image]

And finally this is what it outputs:

> INSERT INTO mk_pay_wages (u_id, year_month, wage) VALUES (14, "2021-06", 900)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month, wage) VALUES (14, "2021-06", 900)' at line 1

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`YEAR_MONTH` is a reserved keyword in MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-Y

You can use a reserved keyword as an identifier only if you enclose it in back-ticks:

```
INSERT INTO mk_pay_wages (u_id, `year_month`, wage) ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you saved my day (my night) I'm dealing with this at midnight in my local time

Comment: But why phpMyAdmin did not tell me this the time of the creation of the table!

Comment: Did you put the column in back-ticks when you created the table?

Comment: no I was created simply with phpMyAdmin and I wrote them without any back-ticks

Comment: I don't use phpmyadmin, but I would guess phpmyadmin added the back-ticks for you. But regardless, there's no way MySQL Server would accept `year_month` as a column name without being delimited with back-ticks.